# Do you even know who I am anymore? What am I?

Tags: riddle

The last time you were hot,
I cooled you down,
And you praised me.

But yesterday you said
I looked "big and fat,"
And I was sad.

Yet today I felt better
when you told all your friends
that I looked like an angel.

When we touch,
I admit I feel like
I'm just annoying you.

Is out-of-sight really
out-of-mind with you? Or do
you miss me when I'm gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer:

> A cloud.

The last time you were hot,
I cooled you down,
And you praised me.

> Clouds cool things down.. with rain and such.

But yesterday you said
I looked "big and fat,"
And I was sad.

> Clouds can be big and fluffy.. the person in question must have taken notice and remarked that the clouds were remarkably big and fat that day?

Yet today I felt better
when you told all your friends
that I looked like an angel.

> Angel, heavens, clouds. Probably a cloud formation that reminded the person in question of an angel.

When we touch,
I admit I feel like
I'm just annoying you.

> Fog is annoying.. reduced visibility and such.

Is out-of-sight really
out-of-mind with you? Or do
you miss me when I'm gone?

> Sometimes there are no clouds in the sky, and usually people are pretty happy about that.